# Should suggesting downgrading a buggy package not be considered an answer?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I have failed [a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12783122). I disagree with the claim that this wasn't an answer to the OP's question. User suggested a solution to the problem and a possible cause. Obviously, the post could contain more information or references to the actual bug, hence in my opinion it should be marked as a post which needs improvement. Deleting posts like this will only discourage new members to reply.

Comment: Voted to undelete.

Comment: Audits like those just highlight the problem of roboreviewers voting to close/delete posts.

Comment: I don't think the problem is robo-reviewers. From the review queue, that answer looks like a "me too" non-answer. It would benefit from an edit explaining exactly what the problem was.

Comment: A "me too" answer would be a statement that someone has that problem. This provided an actual solution by someone who just happened to have a similar issue. Clearly this is an answer.

Comment: @MichaelPetch most of the times, the apparencies matters, way too much for most. That's why we edit posts, to make apparent what should be.

Answer (score 30):

In my opinion it is an answer.

If there is a bug within a specific version of a 3rd party component, the simplest and most correct answer is to downgrade or upgrade to the version where it is fixed.

For some problems with a specific version of a component, you may be totally unable to work around it and the only valuable move is definitively downgrading/upgrading.

Of course SO is not a repository of known bugs on products. But if you encounter that problem, users will be very happy to see it comes from the component and not from their code. Because (fair) users of SO will be more likely to torture their brain on their own code before considering it might be a bug from the library, so I can't see how this would not be an answer to the OP's question nor how it wouldn't be useful to the community.

In your specific case, the user doesn't have a confirmed bug links from Postgres, so we don't know if it's a known break change or a bug. So it may not be the real right answer, but it's still a useful answer.

Comment: This issue reminds me of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 14):

I think that reviewers didn't pay enough attention, probably because the beginning of the answer:

> I had the exact same issue.

The user suggests a solution, for the same problem, that *worked* for him, but didn't provide enough resources. That's not a good reason for deleting the answer - asking answerer to provide more info and improve his answer is what should be done.